# Running Batch file with expdp command inside

Tags: batch-processing

hi i tried to take schema backup in oracle running the below command in c prompt

```
D:\oracle11g\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN>expdp system/password schemas='XYZ' compress=Y directory=expdp_dir dumpfile='expdp_dumpfile_%T.dmp' logfile='c:\dumpfile_exp.log
```

and it worked fine.

But when i tried to put the above command in bat file it is not working

i kept the below code in bat file.

```
@ECHO OFF
D:\Oracle11g\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN expdp system/password schemas='XYZ' compress=Y directory=expdp_dir dumpfile='expdp_dumpfile_%T.dmp' logfile='c:\dumpfile_exp.log

if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
echo    Success
)

if %ERRORLEVEL%==2 (

echo Failed
)
```

i am getting a message as system could not the path and success message.

please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
@ECHO OFF
D:\Oracle11g\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN expdp system/password schemas='XYZ' compress=Y directory=expdp_dir dumpfile='expdp_dumpfile_%T.dmp' logfile='c:\dumpfile_exp.log

if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
echo    Success
)

if %ERRORLEVEL%==2 (

echo Failed
)
```

What I would use:

```
@Echo off
D:\Oracle11g\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN\expdp.exe system/password schemas='XYZ' compress=Y directory=expdp_dir dumpfile='expdp_dumpfile_%T.dmp' logfile='c:\dumpfile_exp.log

if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (echo "Success") else (echo "Failed with error code: " %ERRORLEVEL%)
```

Notice the 2nd line, you put:

```
D:\Oracle11g\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN expdp system/password schemas='XYZ' compress=Y directory=expdp_dir dumpfile='expdp_dumpfile_%T.dmp' logfile='c:\dumpfile_exp.log
```

Notice the second line where I put:

```
D:\Oracle11g\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN\expdp.exe system/password schemas='XYZ' compress=Y directory=expdp_dir dumpfile='expdp_dumpfile_%T.dmp' logfile='c:\dumpfile_exp.log
```